# Devise + LocomotiveCMS - Remember the page I was trying to visit before being asked to log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, locomotivecms

I'm trying to add a simple feature to [locomotivecms](http://locomotivecms.com/) ([github](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine)). A very simple feature: currently users are redirected to the "main admin hub" (/admin/) after logging in - even if they were trying to edit a different page. I want them to be directed to that page after logging in instead.

It seems a very simple and reasonable thing to add, but after two days trying I've decided to ask for help.

This is what I've found out so far.

- This app doesn't use ActiveRecord, but Mongoid (the backend db is MongoDB)
- Locomotive doesn't use a simple "User" schema. Authentication is divided into two parts: "accounts" (email, password, name, etc) and "site" (it's a multi-site cms). A "site" has many "memberhips". A membership has one site_id and account_id (and also, a role, but that's not important for this, I think).
- Most of the "action" in locomotive is behind the `/admin/` route. For example, the login path is `/admin/log_in` . Most controllers are inside an `/admin/` subfolder, too.
- I've found [this bit](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/blob/master/app/controllers/admin/sessions_controller.rb#L14-16) in the `/admin/sessions_controller` that apparently "fixes" the url to be visited after being logged in to the `/admin/` root.

Here's the relevant bit:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  admin_pages_url
end
```

I'm nearly sure that what I need is this instead:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || admin_pages_url
end
```

If I have understood Devise's documentation correctly, `stored_location_for` searches for a value in the session (`session['admin_return_to']` in Locomotive's case) to "see if someone wants to go back somewhere". If it's empty, the || ensures a safe path to the admin root.

Unfortunately this doesn't work. It seems that the session variable that I need is never set up. I was assuming that Devise did this kindof automatically.

Must I set the session value myself? If so, where? Or are my assumptions wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is updating to the latest version of LocomotiveCMS.